# Change an object array into multidimensional array and print

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array. I am retrieving this from UPS RateInTransit API. I am receiving this in an object. Then i convert it into a simple array.
i have received the data into json from UPS. So i converted it into php array by **Json_encode** and **json_decode**.

After that from **Object array** to **simple array**, so i found this.

```
object(Ups\Entity\RateResponse)#81 (1) {
  ["RatedShipment"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Ups\Entity\RatedShipment)#82 (12) {
      ["Service"]=>
      object(Ups\Entity\Service)#83 (3) {
        ["Description"]=>
        NULL
        ["code":"Ups\Entity\Service":private]=>
        string(2) "03"
        ["description":"Ups\Entity\Service":private]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["RateShipmentWarning"]=>
      string(56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
      ["BillingWeight"]=>
      object(Ups\Entity\BillingWeight)#89 (2) {
        ["UnitOfMeasurement"]=>
        object(Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement)#91 (4) {
          ["Code"]=>
          string(3) "LBS"
          ["Description"]=>
          NULL
          ["code":"Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement":private]=>
          string(3) "LBS"
          ["description":"Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement":private]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["Weight"]=>
        string(4) "32.0"
      }
      ["TransportationCharges"]=>
      object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#84 (5) {
        ["CurrencyCode"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["MonetaryValue"]=>
        float(43.17)
        ["Code"]=>
        NULL
        ["Description"]=>
        NULL
        ["SubType"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["ServiceOptionsCharges"]=>
      object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#86 (5) {
        ["CurrencyCode"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["MonetaryValue"]=>
        float(0)
        ["Code"]=>
        NULL
        ["Description"]=>
        NULL
        ["SubType"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["TotalCharges"]=>
      object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#87 (5) {
        ["CurrencyCode"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["MonetaryValue"]=>
        float(43.17)
        ["Code"]=>
        NULL
        ["Description"]=>
        NULL
        ["SubType"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["GuaranteedDaysToDelivery"]=>
      object(stdClass)#72 (0) {
      }
      ["ScheduledDeliveryTime"]=>
      object(stdClass)#73 (0) {
      }
      ["RatedPackage"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Ups\Entity\RatedPackage)#88 (5) {
          ["Weight"]=>
          string(3) "4.0"
          ["BillingWeight"]=>
          object(Ups\Entity\BillingWeight)#95 (2) {
            ["UnitOfMeasurement"]=>
            object(Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement)#97 (4) {
              ["Code"]=>
              string(3) "LBS"
              ["Description"]=>
              NULL
              ["code":"Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement":private]=>
              string(3) "LBS"
              ["description":"Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement":private]=>
              NULL
            }
            ["Weight"]=>
            string(4) "32.0"
          }
          ["TransportationCharges"]=>
          object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#85 (5) {
            ["CurrencyCode"]=>
            string(3) "USD"
            ["MonetaryValue"]=>
            float(43.17)
            ["Code"]=>
            NULL
            ["Description"]=>
            NULL
            ["SubType"]=>
            NULL
          }
          ["ServiceOptionsCharges"]=>
          object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#92 (5) {
            ["CurrencyCode"]=>
            string(3) "USD"
            ["MonetaryValue"]=>
            float(0)
            ["Code"]=>
            NULL
            ["Description"]=>
            NULL
            ["SubType"]=>
            NULL
          }
          ["TotalCharges"]=>
          object(Ups\Entity\Charges)#93 (5) {
            ["CurrencyCode"]=>
            string(3) "USD"
            ["MonetaryValue"]=>
            float(43.17)
            ["Code"]=>
            NULL
            ["Description"]=>
            NULL
            ["SubType"]=>
            NULL
          }
        }
      }
      ["SurCharges"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["TimeInTransit"]=>
      NULL
      ["NegotiatedRates"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

But i am unable to access ***['RatedShipment]['BillingWeight']['Weight']***.
Where did i write a wrong code???

Comment: Is there anything easier to read that you could put in your question? That array var_dump is near impossible to sift through. Could you maybe show `<pre><?=json_encode($result);?></pre>`

Comment: `RatedShipment` is an array, and it is clear as day using numeric keys.

Comment: @Kinglish a json code received from UPS is added into question

Answer (score 0):

What do you think to use `$arr = (array) $obj;`?

Because it still looks like an object.

Or you could access `$obj->RatedShipment->BillingWeight->Weight`?

Comment: its shows error like this : Notice: Trying to get property 'RatedShipment' of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\cncin\web\order_create_shipment.php on line 111